# How do I combine physics fields in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, graph-drawing

I'm writing a three-dimensional [force-directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) in SceneKit where I'm modeling nodes as physical spheres with fixed charges and masses.

These spheres must exert radial gravitational and electrical fields in order to achieve the required dynamics:

> Typically, spring-like attractive forces based on Hooke's law are used
>   to attract pairs of endpoints of the graph's edges towards each other,
>   while simultaneously repulsive forces like those of electrically
>   charged particles based on Coulomb's law are used to separate all
>   pairs of nodes.

The problem arises when one notices that `SCNNode` offers but a single `physicsField` property.

Currently, I see no way to accomplish this without having two separate physical nodes occupy the same space (yuck and impossible?). I've tried inserting child bodies with static/dynamic physical bodies in order to accommodate multiple fields, however this approach does not seem to work at all (i.e. nothing happens).

---

On a somewhat related note - SceneKit's physics engine feels rather incomplete to me, given that 3D force-directed graph drawing falls under typified usage of such frameworks.

For example, SceneKit does not feature a 3D version of `SKPhysicsJointSpring`, making it incredibly tedious to implement node-to-node edge attraction physics. While it *does* feature `SCNPhysicsBehavior`, there is virtually no documentation on subclassing it to create custom behaviors.

Worse still, the public interface offers no methods to override, making reverse-engineering it risky and unsafe for App Store usage:

```
open class SCNPhysicsBehavior : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:* I haven't written any SceneKit code and this is just based on reading the docs, so please take this answer with a good-sized grain of salt.

An `SCNPhysicsField` determines how the position of affected nodes change over time. It's straightforward to handle one field at a time, but not so when different types of fields interact. I suspect it's not possible to be both correct and fast to calculate the effect of multiple fields affecting a node simultaneously, and that's why you can't have combinations of `physicsField`s on a node at a time.

You could however create a custom field in SceneKit with [`SCNPhysicsField.customField()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnphysicsfield/1388140-customfield), and have that field apply only on the children of the field's node. Then, in your implementation of [`SCNFieldForceEvaluator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnfieldforceevaluator), you can perform calculations handling both Hooke's law and Coulomb's law yourself to position all the child nodes.

A simpler but less accurate way (and I'm not sure if it would work) would be to do it purely using electric fields, with a child node's polarity being opposite that of its parent node.

Comment: Purely using electric fields would definitely not work.

Comment: It wouldn't be the same as using Hooke's and Coulumb's laws, but it seems it could provide the basis for a graph visualisation. Can you expand on why you say it would not work?